# How to start thread with function object with argument

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I code snipped below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


class Me{
public:
bool isLearning;
 void operator()(bool startLearning){
  isLearning = startLearning;
 }
};

int main(){
Me m;
std::thread t1(m(true));
t1.join();
std::cout << m.isLearning << std::endl;
}
```

I can't start thread with callable object when argument is passed, is there any way to start thread and pass callable object with argument in thread constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem #1**

`std::thread t1(m(true));` does not do what you think it does.

In this case you are invoking your function object and passing it's result (which is void) to the constructor of [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).

**Solution**

Try passing your function object and arguments like this:

`std::thread(m, true);`

**Problem #2**

`std::thread` will take a copy of your function object so the one it uses and modifies will not be the same one declared in `main`.

**Solution**

Try passing a reference to `m` instead by using `std::ref`.

`std::thread(std::ref(m), true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::thread t1(m, true);
```

Bear in mind that, absent proper synchronisation,

```
isLearning = startLearning;
```

and

```
std::cout << m.isLearning << std::endl;
```

executing simultaneously constitute a data race and undefined behaviour.

Don't forget to `t1.join()` in the end.